# uploading image using multipart content type

Tags: android, post, file-upload

iam developing an android application where i have to upload a photo to the server
in the server side the is the following code

```
echo $_GET['test'];
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000000000)
) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      //insert into datab
  ...... ?>
```

in the mobile app i'm using **HTTPPOST**  and **HTTP client** to send my photo, the problem is when i set my content type to multipart it can not pass the 
    if() statement in php
i have tried to add 2 different content types, using **HTTPURLConnection** instead of client but i can't send my images here is my mobile code

```
private class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Void> {

    private static final String TAG = "upload";

    protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
        if (bitmaps[0] == null)
            return null;
        setProgress(0);

        Bitmap bitmap = bitmaps[0];
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); // convert
                                                                    // Bitmap
                                                                    // to
                                                                    // ByteArrayOutputStream
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()); // convert
                                                                            // ByteArrayOutputStream
                                                                            // to
                                                                            // ByteArrayInputStream
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://10.10.10.98:8888/upload_file.php"); // server
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type",
                    "multipart/form-data; boundary=--14737809831466499882746641449");
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            reqEntity
                    .addPart("myFile", System.currentTimeMillis() + "", in);

            /*
             * httppost.setHeader( "Content-type",
             * "multipart/form-data; boundary=--14737809831466499882746641449"
             * )
             */
            // httppost.setHeader("Content-type","image/jpg\r\n\r\n");

            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
            /*
             * httppost.addHeader( "Content-type",
             * "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"
             * );
             */
            // httppost.addHeader("Content-type","image/jpg\r\n\r\n");
            // httppost.
            // Header h=new Header();

            Log.i(TAG, "request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            try {
                if (response != null)
                    Log.i(TAG, "response "
                            + response.getStatusLine().toString());

            } finally {

            }
        } finally {

        }

        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and here is my `addPart()` function

```
public void addPart(final String key, final String fileName,
        final InputStream fin, String type) {
    writeFirstBoundaryIfNeeds();
    try {
        type = "Content-Type:" + "multipart/form-data; boundary="
                + boundary;
        out.write(type.getBytes());
        out.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name= file; filename=\""
                + fileName + ".jpeg\"\r\n").getBytes());

        type = "Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n ";
        out.write(type.getBytes());

        /*
         * out.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=\""
         * + fileName + ".jpeg\"\r\n").getBytes());
         */
        // out.write(type.getBytes());
        out.write("\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n"
                .getBytes());

        final byte[] tmp = new byte[4096];
        int l = 0;
        while ((l = fin.read(tmp)) != -1) {
            out.write(tmp, 0, l);
        }
        out.flush();
    } catch (final IOException e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            fin.close();
        } catch (final IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `it can not pass the if() statement in php`. Which if statement?

Comment: Your `addPart` function has four parameters but you call it with three.